# How to track URL when loging php errors

Tags: php

I have file errors login enabled: 
@ini_set('log_errors', 1);
@ini_set('error_log', $debug_logfile_path);

It works fine but I would like to also log the current url in the same log file with the error: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI].
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that information is available and can be written to a log file. Will you elaborate on the way that you would like to use this information, and how your attempts failed to meet your goal?

Comment: Surely the PHP Error log reports the actual path and filename where an error occurs so why do you need this extra information

Comment: I need to know not only the file path but also page url where the error happened. I cannot find how to add to the errors files some extra informtion. all i have are these init_set functions but I cannot add anything there.